# Convert SQL Query to LINQ ORDER BY, GROUP BY, COUNT

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I'm having a hard time converting this query to LINQ. Can you guys help me.

```
select ChoiceID, count(ChoiceID) as aValue 
from QuestionNumber inner join 
     TestAnswer 
     on QuestionNumber.QNID = TestAnswer.QNID 
where QuestionNumber.QuestionID = 30 
group by ChoiceID 
order by aValue desc
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), and show your own first efforts so we see where *specifically* you need help. The best LINQ query is hardly ever a 1:1 reproduction of a SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from qNo in QuestionNumber
            join tAnswer in TestAnswer on
            qNo.QNID equals tAnswer.QNID into qAnswer
            group qAnswer by qNo.ChoiceId
            where qNo.QuestionId == 30
            select new { ChoiceId = qNo.ChoiceId, 
                         QCount = qAnswer.Count() }
            orderby qAsnwer.QCount descending
```

Comment: I think it should be like this: `var query = (from qn in QuestionNumber join ta in TestAnswer on qn.QNID equals ta.QNID where qn.QuestionID == 30 group qn by qn.ChoiceId into group1 select new { ChoiceId = qn.ChoiceId, aValue = group1.Count() }).OrderByDescending(x => x.aValue);`.

Comment: I think `orderby qAsnwer.QCount descending` must added before `select`, and seems aggregate `OrderByDescending` is more preferred because at this point `QCount` is not defined yet.